# Windows not using manually set IP Address

Tags: windows, dhcp, gateway, static-ip

Recently my windows machine that has been working without a problem for over a year decided to start using a dynamic IP address instead of the static one I manually configured it to use. The only recent change we had was adding an Ethernet splitter between the server and gateway in order to add an additional server to the network, however that was about 2 months ago so I don't know why that would cause it to start acting up now.

Below is a few things I tried without success

*I've tried to /release & /renew the IP, but that didn't do anything

*I've tried to restart the computer but that just got me a different dynamic IP or kept the same IP from last time

*I've tried to access the Gateway config page, however for there seems to be a problem with that as well (I typed the Default Gateway IP into the browser, and the page continuously loaded til it timed out).

I'm thinking this may be a problem with the Gateway due to the problems I'm having accessing the config page for that, but before I call comcast I would like to make sure it isn't just some quick fix I'm missing.

Comment: @Zoredache [This is an Ethernet Splitter](http://www.primuscable.com/store/p/1287-Ethernet-Splitter-for-PC-s-Pigtail-Type-10-100-BaseT-1P-2J-04.aspx]) (P.S. They're terrible)

Comment: Does your IP address start with `169.254.x.x`? If so then this is a link-local address and is not a DHCP address.

Comment: @Wesley, I doubt that is what the OP is talking about.  Also, those doen't really split the ethernet, it just lets you use extra pairs on a CAT5 connection.  You still need extra ports on the switch/hub for each connection, you just save yourself a cable run.

Comment: Where was the static IP assigned? In the router, with Windows configured for DHCP, or in the Windows TCP/IP configuration? I have had problems with the former, but never with the latter, but you must make sure you choose an address which is not in the router's DHCP pool?

Comment: @Wesley I'm using an Ethernet Switch similar to this (http://tinyurl.com/mb4xrmw - I got the term wrong in my question). As far as the IP goes I believe it's a TCP/IP configuration (my IP starts with 192.168.100). I'm basically using the set-up described here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether your cabling is correct or your ISP has messed something up, if u set up a static IP on the server in the network settings, the server will try to use the static IP and it would show up if you ran `ipconfig`; even if the IP you set doesn't allow for network communication. My first guess is that you didn't actually set a static ip in the first place and your dhcp lease was set for an inactivity time or since you only had 1 server it just issued the same IP every time.

Since you have a router/gateway , ill assume you have NAT. If that's the case you need to set the public static IP on the public router interface and a private static IP on the server and confirm the port forwarding rules on the router.

If there was a direct connection from the server to the router and you put a switch in between to connect more servers, make sure the switch is working if you haven't already. Then see what IP address the other machines on the switch are getting. The fact u implemented new servers could cause the dhcp to issue IPs to other servers instead of the desired one.

Answer (score -1):

Im guessing this dynamic IP you're talking about is windows private ip system... or you get a Gateway and DHCP Server IP Address?.

I believe you split your network (using something like a switch?), but for some reason seems like you locked yourself out of the network.

I didn't fully understand your question but i'd check:
-Gateway (Router), has a LAN port connected to a port on a Switch.
-Connect your computer, to this Switch.
-I assume your gateway has the DHCP server.

Otherwise, i'd try with another cable, many times I've seen cables acting funny... If that doesn't work, please add more details to the question... Like the net, what's connected where, and what devices you have. Ie. Linksys WRT54G, Switch Encore, Network cards Realtek.

Comment: As far as accessing the gateway/router goes I don't think it's a problem with the Switch or Cable. I also tried accessing the login page from some of our other computers which use a completely different port on the router and it doesn't seem to work there either.